# How to change a color of a Bar in chart automatically depend on data conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have done a chart of sale data but i need to change a color of some bar that point of data is not reach the target sale by automatically depend on condition

this is my present chart

[Present Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQiHl.jpg)

i need a formulas for it or Vb Maybe

this is what i want.

[Predict Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3cH3.jpg)

Comment: Have a duplicate row of data using an if() to put 0 if the data meets your minimum... then plot as data series in red...

Comment: I'll try thanks you

Comment: That's work thanks bro @SolarMike

Comment: I do like the simple solutions - best of luck!